# Forcibly Suggesting Combo Box Auto Complete Mode To None - C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, metroframework

I am using Metro Frame Work Combo Box in my WinForm,

When I try to set `cmbCACName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append;` it is throwing an exception like 'AutoCompleteMode.None can be used when DropDownStyle is ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList'.

Here is my code

```
cmbCACName.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.Simple;
cmbCACName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append;
cmbCACName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
```

Here is an exception:
[image]

I could not understand what is happening.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Here is the reason for the exception:

- In metro framework, the `DropDownStyle` property of the `MetroComboBox` has been overridden to always set `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList`.
- In other hand, in `ComboBox`, the `AutoCompleteMode` property contains a validation rule, to throw an exception whenever the value of `AutoCompleteMode` is set to a value other than `None`.

So, the first line of your code is technically setting `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList`. So in the second line, assigning `Append` to `AutoCompleteMode` will result in an exception.

[*MetroComboBox.DropDownList*](https://github.com/thielj/MetroFramework/blob/master/MetroFramework/Controls/MetroComboBox.cs#L55)

```
[DefaultValue(ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList)]
[Browsable(false)]
public new ComboBoxStyle DropDownStyle
{
    get { return ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList; }
    set { base.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList; }
}
```

[*ComboBox.AutoCompleteMode*](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBox.cs,177)

```
DefaultValue(AutoCompleteMode.None),
SRDescription(SR.ComboBoxAutoCompleteModeDescr),
Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)
]
public AutoCompleteMode AutoCompleteMode {
    get {
        return autoCompleteMode;
    }
    set {
        //valid values are 0x0 to 0x3
        if (!ClientUtils.IsEnumValid(value, (int)value, (int)AutoCompleteMode.None, (int)AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend)) {
            throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("value", (int)value, typeof(AutoCompleteMode));
        }
        if (this.DropDownStyle == ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList &&
            this.AutoCompleteSource != AutoCompleteSource.ListItems &&
            value != AutoCompleteMode.None) {
            throw new NotSupportedException(SR.GetString(SR.ComboBoxAutoCompleteModeOnlyNoneAllowed));
        }
        if (Application.OleRequired() != System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA) {
            throw new ThreadStateException(SR.GetString(SR.ThreadMustBeSTA));
        }
        bool resetAutoComplete = false;
        if (autoCompleteMode != AutoCompleteMode.None && value == AutoCompleteMode.None) {
            resetAutoComplete = true;
        }
        autoCompleteMode = value;
        SetAutoComplete(resetAutoComplete, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: so how can I handle this?

Comment: For `MetroComboBox` you can use just `DropDownList` as `DropDownStyle`. Anyway, I hope the answer help you to *understand what is happening*.

Comment: Yes, But my issue was not resolved, I need auto complete mode as append

Comment: Is there any way to change metro form title background color? and when I adding border styles for metro grid headers and cells again it forcibly resetting to none.

Comment: Same like above I am not able to add text to the metro combo box, I am assigning string value to combo box text property, but after adding it showing empty

Comment: I believe the answer is clear. *MetroComboBox* just supports `DropDownList` as `DropDownStyle`.

Comment: About other questions which you asked in comments, unfortunately I have no idea. I suggest asking those questions in separate posts. Take a look at [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts)